# paginate_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'view'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

while running the below code getting the "paginate_queryset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'view'" error after adding pagination

views.py

```
class UsersList(ListAPIView,LimitOffsetPagination):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsVerified,permissions.IsAdminUser)


    @swagger_auto_schema(
        query_serializer=PaginationSerializer,
        responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: UserOutputSerializer(many=True)},
        operation_id="list_users",
    )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = User.objects.filter(is_verified=True, is_active=True).order_by('user_name')
        results = self.paginate_queryset(qs, request, view=self)
        users = UserOutputSerializer(results, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(users.data)
```

urls.py

```
path('list_users/',UsersList.as_view(),name='list_users'),
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to pass in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding all the good stuff about `ListAPIView` by overriding the `get` method like that. If you want to user `swagger_auto_schema`, then try like this:

```
class UsersList(ListAPIView,LimitOffsetPagination):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsVerified,permissions.IsAdminUser)
    serializer_class = UserOutputSerializer
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_verified=True, is_active=True).order_by('user_name')
   
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        query_serializer=PaginationSerializer,
        responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: UserOutputSerializer(many=True)},
        operation_id="list_users",
    )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```